# How can I select a row with exclusively one value?

Tags: mysql, select

This is how my table looks:

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ USER ║ COLOR ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ a    ║ Red   ║
║ b    ║ Blue  ║
║ c    ║ Blue  ║
║ b    ║ Red   ║
║ a    ║ Red   ║
║ c    ║ White ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

I've just need the rows which has *exclusively* color=  "Red". 
It must return "a" ("b" contains value "Blue" too).

How can I set the select?

Comment: +1, for a well formatted question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where color = 'red'
  and exists (select user
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.user = t2.user
              group by user
              having count(distinct color) = 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecba2/8)

Or without the subquery you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable
group by user
HAVING  SUM(color = 'red') = COUNT(*)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45fa1/9)

Answer (score 2):

TRY his query

```
Select * 
from tbl 
where color = 'RED' AND USER not in 
(Select USER from tbl where color <> 'RED');
```